# QWebException: "Expected singleton: supply.conditions(675, 676)" while evaluating

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9, qweb

I have qweb template:

```
<tr t-foreach="company.supply_conditions_status" t-as="supply">
   <td>
      <span t-field="supply.vendor"/>
   </td>
</tr>
```

my field from *.py file:

```
supply_conditions_status = fields.One2many('supply.conditions', 'purchase_id', string='Order',copy=True)
```

Got an error:

```
QWebException: "Expected singleton: supply.conditions(675, 676)" while evaluating 'company.supply_conditions_status.vendor'
```

I understand that the problem is that I get tuple. I was trying to use loop but it doesn't work. What can it be solutions to get data from `supply_conditions_status`?

Comment: The loop is fine, are you sure thats where it raises the Error? dont you have a company.supply_conditions_status.vendor somewhere?

Comment: Shame on me. That was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Great, i will post it as the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is fine, the problem is that you have company.supply_conditions_status.vendor somewhere else in the code, loop or remove it :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem that  `vendor` field is also a one2many that contains more than one record  `supply.conditions(675, 676)`

```xml
<tr t-foreach="company.supply_conditions_status" t-as="supply">
   <td>
      <t t-foreach="supply.vendor" t-as="vendor">
        <span  t-field="vendor"/>,
     </t>
   </td>
</tr>
```